# How to run a script in DB2 along with other sqls

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, db2

I had a doubt regarding DB2. I created a script for example.

```
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM ABC;
END
```

Now I want to run it in a report generator where I already have some select queries with joins and everything. The script has a purpose of reading input and parsing that string and store details in a temporary table (this part is done). Now my other select queries will work on this table.

But how do I put both these things in one file or should I create separate files (a procedure from script and execute it in sql report). But I want to know if there is a way of doing it in same file.

Comment: in an .sql file? Your question is not clear.

Comment: Yes, i'll try to explain.
I already have a .sql file which has lot of select qurries to generate a report. Now i needed to modify some information coming from user. So i created a script for that but now i do not understand where do i put that script. i tried putting the script block in the same file on the top but it's not working. I hope i am clear now.

Comment: May be you need to change the statement terminator in your `.sql` file to something other than semicolon?

Comment: Hi mustaccio, are you suggesting something like DELIMITER, coz i've tried that and that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Please, rewrite your answer. What is the input, what is the desired output, and what is the process. Also, use the formatting for code

Comment: "_i've tried that and that doesn't seem to work_" -- Staying at the same level of detail, try it again but differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In DB2 there is no way to deal with standard input when using scripts in db2clp. This console is only to send commands to DB2, but the commands should already be prepared.

In order to deal with user input, you use shell scripts, like .bat in Windows or bash/korn shell scripts. With these scripts you take the user input, and then construct the commands to send to DB2.

```
read id
db2 "select * from emp where id = ${id}"
```

For the previous approach, you need to create scripts for each platform (windows and *NIX-bash or korn)

However, there is another way to deal with user input in DB2 but you need to use CLPPlus. This is like SQL*Plus, and you can get the input from the user into a variable, and then query the database with that value.

Comment: I have use CLPPlus a couple of times, not so much, but I think there are minor errors in that console.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is an anonymous block. When you call the script, it is executed, but it does not return any output. You need a stored procedure in order to retrieve a result set.

Comment: Yes i understand that, but isn't the data i'm storing in table will exist?

Comment: The table in the data will always exist because you are not executing DML (delete, update, delete). You need to retrieve the rows from the table, and fetch them.

Comment: Are you asking some information to the user in order to create your query? For example: give me userId. Then select * from emps where userId = XXX

Comment: I mean, do you need to pass some information to the query (parameter marker, or parameter in a stored procedure)?

Comment: I will get some IDs (Space seperated numbers) from user and now i need to fetch some information from database for these IDs. So i created a script to parse the input to separate all the Ids and put them in a table. So that i can simply use these Ids to fetch details. Now i don't understand how can i use this script with existing .sql